# Understanding the process of loading multiple file contents into Dask Array and how it scales

Tags: dask

Using the example on http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array-creation.html

```
filenames = sorted(glob('2015-*-*.hdf5')
dsets = [h5py.File(fn)['/data'] for fn in filenames]
arrays = [da.from_array(dset, chunks=(1000, 1000)) for dset in dsets]
x = da.concatenate(arrays, axis=0)  # Concatenate arrays along first axis
```

I'm having trouble understanding the next line and whether its a dask_array of "dask arrays" or a "normal" np array which points to as many dask arrays as there were datasets in all the hdf5 files that gets returned.

Is there any increase in performance (thread or memory based) during the file read stage as a result of the `da.from_array` or is only when you concatenate into the dask array `x` where you should expect improvements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects in the `arrays` list are all dask arrays, one for each file.

The `x` object is also a dask array that combines all of the results of the dask arrays in the `arrays` list.  It isn't a dask.array of dask arrays, it's just a single flattened dask array with an a larger first dimension.

There will probably not be an increase in performance for reading data.  You're likely to be I/O bound by your disk bandwidth.  Most people in this situation are using dask.array because they have more data than can conveniently fit into RAM.  If this isn't valuable to you then I would stick with NumPy.