# Improve performance of Dask array calculating a stencil

Tags: python, parallel-processing, benchmarking, dask

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40117237/how-to-programm-a-stencil-with-dask%20%22%22) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42939653/3d-volume-processing-using-dask) question, it seems that the Dask-ish way to program a stecil is using `dask.array.map_blocks` with `dask.array.ghost` or `dask.array.map_overlap`. So I have the following code:

```
def local_stencil(block):
    block[1:-1,1:-1,1:-1] = ( block[1:-1,1:-1,1:-1] + block[0:-2,1:-1,1:-1] + block[2:,1:-1,1:-1] + block[1:-1,0:-2,1:-1] + block[1:-1,2:,1:-1] + block[1:-1,1:-1,0:-2] + block[1:-1,1:-1,2:]) / 7.0;
    return block

def stencil(grid, iterations, workers):
    g = da.ghost.ghost(grid, depth={0:1, 1:1, 2:1}, boundary={0:0, 1:1, 2:0})
    chunk_size = int(math.pow( g.shape[0]**3/workers, 1/3))
    for iteration in range(iterations):
        g = da.from_array( g.map_blocks(local_stencil).compute(), chunks=chunk_size)
    return da.ghost.trim_internal(g, {0:1, 1:1, 2:1})
```

I don't know why when compared to a numpy version of the same stencil function (`local_stencil`) it performs considerably worse:
[image]

Are there any changes I can make to my code to improve performance?

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171316/understanding-the-process-of-loading-multiple-file-contents-into-dask-array-and) other answer, I understand how Dask is helpful when you have a file larger than RAM memory, but could Dask also be helpful in compute-bound operations like matrix multiplications or convolution operations?

Comment: I see that you do `da.from_array(arr.compute())` repeatedly: this is an anti-pattern, because you pull the whole dataset into the local thread, and then send the data out again. Will `g = g.map_blocks(..)` work?

Comment: @mdurant, I changed `g = da.from_array( g.map_blocks(local_stencil).compute(), chunks=chunk_size)` to simply `g = g.map_blocks(local_stencil)` and actually it runs faster, but outputs a different result.

Comment: You may find this interesting https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/2244

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to collaborate in that thread.